# Is there any way to cast a Callback<MouseEvent> into FnMut(MouseEvent)?

Tags: rust, lifetime, yew, web-sys

I'm implementing material 3 from scratch with [web_sys](https://docs.rs/web-sys/latest/web_sys/) and writing some adapters for different frameworks among them [yew](https://yew.rs/).

I have implemented a basic structure for buttons something [like this](https://gitlab.com/material-rs/material_you_rs/-/blob/agnostic-api/crates/core/src/components/buttons/mod.rs?ref_type=heads#L119) to use [like this](https://gitlab.com/material-rs/material_you_rs/-/blob/agnostic-api/examples/basics/src/buttons/elevated.rs?ref_type=heads#L6).

This works fine on web_sys but I'm trying to write the yew adapter and I'm having problems by casting between [`yew::Callback<web_sys::MouseEvent>`](https://docs.rs/yew/latest/yew/callback/struct.Callback.html) to [`FnMut(web_sys::MouseEvent)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html).

My adapter looks like this...

[this](https://gitlab.com/material-rs/material_you_rs/-/blob/agnostic-api/crates/core/src/components/buttons/mod.rs?ref_type=heads#L119) is the definition for button in my [core](https://gitlab.com/material-rs/material_you_rs/-/tree/agnostic-api/crates/core?ref_type=heads) module

And this is the definition in my adapter crate:

In adapter props takes both [InnerData](https://gitlab.com/material-rs/material_you_rs/-/blob/agnostic-api/crates/core/src/components/buttons/mod.rs?ref_type=heads#L113) and [ComponentOpts](https://gitlab.com/material-rs/material_you_rs/-/blob/agnostic-api/crates/core/src/components/buttons/mod.rs?ref_type=heads#L107) in one structure

```rust
// the properties in yew adapter
#[derive(PartialEq, Properties)]
pub struct ElevatedButtonProps {
    pub label: AttrValue,

    #[prop_or(false)]
    pub disable: bool,

    #[prop_or_default]
    pub icon: Option<AttrValue>,

    #[prop_or_default]
    pub onclick: Option<Callback<MouseEvent>>,
}
```

And the functional component in yew, which is the adapter per se, takes the properties passed to it and with them creates the button with my "core" library and returns it as a virtual node of yew.

```rust
/// this is my core library https://gitlab.com/material-rs/material_you_rs/-/tree/agnostic-api/crates/core?ref_type=heads
use core::components::buttons::elevated::{self, ElevatedButtonData, ElevatedButtonOpts};
use web_sys::{HtmlElement, MouseEvent};
use yew::{function_component, virtual_dom::VNode, AttrValue, Callback, Html, Properties};


#[function_component(ElevatedButton)]
pub fn elevated_button(props: &ElevatedButtonProps) -> Html {
    let ElevatedButtonProps {
        label,
        disable,
        icon,
        onclick,
    } = props;

    let icon = if let Some(icon) = icon {
        Some(icon.to_string())
    } else {
        None
    };

    let inner = if let Some(onclick) = onclick {
        // problem is here when i'm trying to cast
        let cb = move |e: MouseEvent| {
            onclick.clone().emit(e.clone());
        };

        ElevatedButtonData {
            label: label.to_string(),
            icon,
            onclick: Some(Box::new(cb.clone())),
        }
    } else {
        ElevatedButtonData {
            label: label.to_string(),
            icon,
            onclick: None,
        }
    };

    let opts = ElevatedButtonOpts { disable: *disable };

    let button: HtmlElement = elevated::ElevatedButton::new(inner, opts);

    VNode::VRef(button.into())
}
```

But this is not working...

The compiler tells me that the `yew::Callback` must outlive `'static`, but at the same time the macro annotation `function_component` does not allow me lifetimes annotations.

```
20 | pub fn elevated_button(props: &ElevatedButtonProps) -> Html {
   |                               - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
42 |             onclick: Some(Box::new(cb.clone())),
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cast requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`
```

does anyone have any idea how I can deal with this?

edit:

"core" is my library where I'm implementing the components only over web_sys and in the adapter I'm "instantiating" it in a comfortable way depending on the framework of the shift

Comment: Can you please make a [**minimal** reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? There is a lot of noise here.

Comment: There is no module `components` in [`core`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/index.html) can you please elaborate what you mean? (Or preferably if possible remove the unnecessary parts and include definitions of the necessary ones.)

Comment: I'm sorry, core is my component library, I just updated my question, I hope it is more readable now.

Comment: Please don't link to external resources for additional context, if it's relevant include definitions, if not remove the `use` statement and their use.

Comment: Try to `onclick.clone()` **outside** of the `move || {}`. By calling `.clone()` inside, you move first, then clone. Which makes the entire cloning pointless. Although I of course can't verify, because your example is too convoluted. Please provide a [mre].
The `clone` on the `MouseEvent` can be removed entirely, it's pretty pointless. You already own the value, you just simple create a second one and discard the first one. Use the first one directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your example is too complex and incomplete to be reproduced, I will assume that the following is your actual example:

```rust
pub fn convert_callback(
    onclick: &yew::Callback<web_sys::MouseEvent>,
) -> impl FnMut(web_sys::MouseEvent) {
    let cb = move |e: web_sys::MouseEvent| {
        onclick.clone().emit(e.clone());
    };
    cb
}
```

```
error[E0700]: hidden type for `impl FnMut(MouseEvent)` captures lifetime that does not appear in bounds
 --> src\lib.rs:7:5
  |
2 |     onclick: &yew::Callback<web_sys::MouseEvent>,
  |              ----------------------------------- hidden type `[closure@src\lib.rs:4:14: 4:43]` captures the anonymous lifetime defined here
3 | ) -> impl FnMut(web_sys::MouseEvent) {
  |      ------------------------------- opaque type defined here
...
7 |     cb
  |     ^^
  |
help: to declare that `impl FnMut(MouseEvent)` captures `'_`, you can add an explicit `'_` lifetime bound
  |
3 | ) -> impl FnMut(web_sys::MouseEvent) + '_ {
  |                                      ++++
```

The reason this fails is because you `clone()` the `onclick` object **inside** of the closure, moving it first **before** you clone it.

Also, as a minor remark, cloning `e` is pretty pointless as you already own it. It just creates a copy, then discards the original object. Use the original object directly instead.

Then, it should compile:

```rust
pub fn convert_callback(
    onclick: &yew::Callback<web_sys::MouseEvent>,
) -> impl FnMut(web_sys::MouseEvent) {
    let onclick = onclick.clone();
    let cb = move |e: web_sys::MouseEvent| {
        onclick.emit(e);
    };
    cb
}
```

You can also put those two actions into a nested scope, if you don't want to leak the cloned `onclick` object into the outer scope:

```rust
pub fn convert_callback(
    onclick: &yew::Callback<web_sys::MouseEvent>,
) -> impl FnMut(web_sys::MouseEvent) {
    let cb = {
        let onclick = onclick.clone();
        move |e: web_sys::MouseEvent| {
            onclick.emit(e);
        }
    };
    cb
}
```

Comment: This works, really thanks, I was stuck here a lot hours trying it.  I was even trying to manually implement `FnMut` for a new type, I hadn't noticed the error.

Comment: @al3x Be glad you have the borrow checker, in other languages (especially C++) this would have been a silent error that would cause undefined behavior and would be very hard to find.

Comment: Indeed! It's one of the reasons I love rust! Sometimes it can be a bit painful, but it's worth it.